# Typescript How to change TH row background color with CSS

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Quite simple as question, but I read a lot of other answer and none of them satisfy me.
So my problem is that I have a table and I want to change background color of rows and header depends on the TEAM object, each team have a specific color.

I have a dropdown list giving a list of teams. When I select a team, I'm able to modify my variable and put the name inside my variable and the color inside another variable.

In my HTML for the component , I have :

```
    <!-- Header row third group -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-third-group">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="5" class="tableHeaderCellDivThirdrRow"> {{teamName(2)}}
  </th>
</ng-container>
```

the CSS file :

```
.tableHeaderCellDivThirdrRow { 
   background-color: green;  
}
```

I pass the teamName1 and the teamColor to the component.
I'm calling a function that grab the name from my variable receive from the main component:

TS file :

```
@Input() teamName1: string;
@Input() teamColor1: string;

public teamName(_teamId) {
if (_teamId == 1) {
  return this.teamName1
}
if (_teamId == 2) {
  return this.teamName2
}
```

}

So in my component I can easily print the team name. But I want in my TS file, changing my CSS background-color:  from green  to the parameter teamColor1.

Right now I'm using a SCSS file, (I Read that I can't modify a SCSS file), but I can change it for a CSS file if it's easier.
Also almost answer that I read has color pre-defined in the CSS file. I don't want that because if I add a team with a new color I don't want to came to change the CSS file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<th mat-header-cell [style.background-color]="teamColor1" *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="5"> {{teamName(2)}} </th>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's exactly the answer I DIDN'T WANT. If you read my last line of my question ,I said : Also almost answer that I read has color pre-defined in the CSS file. I don't want that because if I add a team with a new color I don't want to came to change the CSS file.

Comment: I see. Can you try this then: `<th mat-header-cell [style.background-color]="teamColor1" *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="5"> {{teamName(2)}}
</th>`.

Comment: Thank Nenad. I use [style.background-color]="this.Color1" . In my TS file I just write this: this.Color1 = this.teamColor1.BackgroundColor;

Comment: I am glad that helped you. Consider approving and accepting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I vote on you comment. The answer was not the good one, but your comment was. I can't vote for the Answer because it doesn't reflect the reality. But you can see I vote for your comment !

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer for the convenience, if someone else come to this question.